# How to run multiple tensorflow codes in one GPU

Tags: tensorflow

Because of less GPU memory occupied by my codes, I would like to run multiple copy of the same code on one GPU.

I have set that os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0", and also set

```
t_config = tf.ConfigProto()
t_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
with tf.Session(config=t_config) as sess:
```

But when I start the second code, it will report "Failed to create session". I searched from Google and found most people said it is Okay for multiple codes in one GPU.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How much memory is actually allocated to the first TensorFlow process, and how much GPU memory is available (via `nvidia-smi`)? Does fiddling with `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` (i.e. capping memory) help?

Comment: The GPU memory is 8G, and I set per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3 for each pocy of the code. Actually, each copy of the codes only take around of 200M GPU memory.

Comment: Just tried with tf-nightly-gpu and your code works for me (i.e. I can start several sessions on the same GPU). Does it help if you set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` on the command line rather than in the Python process (sometimes that can be iffy)? Does the startup logging for TF mention just the one device?

Comment: This is on my office GPU and any other package like  tf-nightly-gpu cannot be installed. Actually, I also set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES in the python script. If I set it on the command line, can I exit from the command and then use python xx.py to run my script?

Comment: Which TensorFlow version are you using? The exact command I'm using is `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" python3.6 tryproc.py`, which with Bash should set the environmental variable for the whole Python process. But you can also look at the logging output when you first create a session, which will tell you whether there are multiple visible devices (there should be a "Found device 0" line and no "Found device 1").

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is for your second code,first just run  the second code  and test it works fine,then run with each other

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, these two copy of codes are the same..I am not sure why. It is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem as well, the solution is simply to wait a couple of seconds before executing the second script.

So your execution sequence could look like this:

```
python main.py
sleep 30s; python main.py
```

Unfortunately, I don't have an answer as to why this occurs.